# Calling MVTDST function (written in fortran and the body of pmvnorm function in R) from C. Calling fortran from C

Tags: c, r, gcc, gfortran

I would like to compute CDF of multivariate normal distribution in C. This could be easily done by pmvnorm function in R and the body of the pmvnorm function is MVTDST function, which is written in fortran and publically available at http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/software/software.html.

My goal is to use MVDST function in C. I downloaded mvtdstpack.f (which contains the definition of MVTDST) from http://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/genz/software/fort77/mvtdstpack.f.
As this file contains the test program of MVTDST I deleted PROGRAM TSTMVT.

Now to link MVTDST to C, I wrote the following C codes in "CtoF.c".

```
 # include<stdio.h>

 extern void  MVTDST_(int*, int*, double[], double[],int[], double[], double[], 
                  int*, double*, double*, double*, double*, int*);

 int main()
 {
   int N=3; // 3 dimension
   int NU=0; // df=0  <=> normal
   double lower[N];
   double upper[N];
   lower[0] = 0.0000000;
   lower[1] = 0.0000000;
   lower[2] = -0.5773503;
   upper[0] = -1.0000000;
   upper[1] = 2.8000000;
   upper[2] = 0.2886751;
   int INTFIN[N];
   INTFIN[0] = 0;
   INTFIN[1] = 0;
   INTFIN[2] = 2;
   double CORREL[N*(N-1)/2]; 
   // The number of off-diagonal upper triangle entries in N by N square matrix is: N*(N-1)/2
   double DELTA[N];
   DELTA[0] = 0;
   DELTA[1] = 0;
   DELTA[2] = 0;
   int MAXPTS = 25000; // ?? algorithm$maxpts
   double ABSEPS = 0.001;
   double RELEPS = 0;
   double ERROR = 0;
   double VALUE = 1000; // The value will be contained here
   int INFORM = 0;

   MVTDST_(&N,       // N      INTEGER, the number of variables. 
         &NU,      // NU     INTEGER, the number of degrees of freedom. 
         lower,    // LOWER DOUBLE PRECISION, array of lower integration limits. 
         upper,    // UPPER  DOUBLE PRECISION, array of upper integration limits.
         INTFIN,   // INFIN INTEGER, array of integration limits flags
         CORREL, 
         DELTA,   // DELTA DOUBLE PRECISION, array of non-centrality parameters.
         &MAXPTS,     
         &ABSEPS,  // ABSEPS, DOUBLE PRECISION absolute error tolerance.
         &RELEPS,  // RELEPS DOUBLE PRECISION relative error tolerance.
         &ERROR,   // ERROR  DOUBLE PRECISION estimated absolute error,  
         &VALUE,   // VALUE  DOUBLE PRECISION estimated value for the integral 
         &INFORM      
         );
   printf("VALUE %f",VALUE);
   return 0;
   }
```

For compiling, I wrote the following codes on my Mac (Version 10.7.5) terminal:

```
 gcc -c CtoF.c 
 gfortran -c mvtdstpack.f
 gcc -o pleaseWork1 CtoF.o mvtdstpack.o  -lgfortran
```

Then I get the following compilation error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file mvtdstpack.o, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_MVTDST_", referenced from:
    _main in CtoF.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I interpreted this error as the architectures are mixed among the built .o files. So my second attempt was to build everything in 32 bit:

```
 gcc -c -m32 CtoF.c
 gfortran -c -m32 mvtdstpack.f
 gcc -m32 -o  pleaseWork2 CtoF.o mvtdstpack.o  -lgfortran
```

However, I am still getting the same error messages:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_MVTDST_", referenced from:
  _main in CtoF.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Now, I tried:

```
 gcc -c CtoF.c -arch i386
 gfortran -c mvtdstpack.f -arch i386
 gcc -o pleaseWork3 CtoF.o mvtdstpack.o -arch i386
```

Then, I got a different warning messages:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   "_MVTDST_", referenced from:
    _main in CtoF.o
   "__gfortran_st_write_done", referenced from:
    _MAIN__ in mvtdstpack.o
  "__gfortran_transfer_real", referenced from:
  _MAIN__ in mvtdstpack.o
  "__gfortran_pow_r8_i4", referenced from:
   _mvtdns_ in mvtdstpack.o
   _mvchnv_ in mvtdstpack.o
  "__gfortran_set_std", referenced from:
  _MAIN__ in mvtdstpack.o
  "__gfortran_transfer_integer", referenced from:
  _MAIN__ in mvtdstpack.o
  "__gfortran_st_write", referenced from:
  _MAIN__ in mvtdstpack.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It would be great if someone can help me understand what is going on...
I highly appreciate any help...

P.S.
If the MVTDST function is properly linked to 'CtoF.c', it should behave the same as R script:

```
 library(mvtnorm)
 sigma <- matrix( c(1,0.3,0.2,
                    0.3,1,0.6,
                    0.2,0.6,3),3,3)
 lower <- c(-Inf,-Inf,-1)
 upper <- c(2,3,0.5)
 algorithm = GenzBretz()
 pmv <- pmvnorm(lower=lower,upper=upper,mean=mean,sigma=sigma,algorithm = algorithm)
```

Comment: You need to create a shared object, which is, AFAIK is called .dylib on Mac. Please read this tutorial http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html. Oh, and one more thing, you need to link with gfortran; your attempt to pass `-lgfortran` was OK.

Comment: The problem in your situation is the difference in case (in)sensitivity of C and Fortran. C is case sensitive and Fortran is not. Fortran compilers usually convert names to lowercase. C compiler don't and take what you declared and call exactly as typed. So in your case convert the Fortran subroutine names in the C program to lowercase. And then it should work. It did for me. You do not need to create a shared object. And do link with the gfortran.

Comment: @Bhas  Oh my goodness! It worked and this is such a simple trick! Thank you very very much! I want to accept your answer as a solution but you commented..